# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, (list(map))

Tags: python-2.7

So here is my code

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, coords):
        super(Shape, self).__init__()
        self._coords = list(map(list, coords))

    def move(self,distance):
        self._coords = distance

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self._coords[key]

class Point(Shape):
    def __init__(self,coords):
        super(Point, self).__init__(coords)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = Point((0, 0))

    p.move((1, 1))
    assert p[0, 0], p[0, 1] == (1, 1)
```

Basically I want to create a subclass Point from the parent class Shape.
The init part of shape shall stay the same and try to create a new point and pass the test under "main".

This code as it is now gets an error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I am stuck of solutions to this as a beginner in python. What arguments can I pass to _coords to be accepted? How can I connect Point and Shape?

Comment: Can you include your full error stack trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File point.py, line 20, in <module>
    p = Point((0, 0))
  File point.py, line 14, in __init__
    super(Point, self).__init__(coords)
  File point.py, line 4, in __init__
    self._coords = list(map(list, coords))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, coords):
        super(Shape, self).__init__()
        self._coords = list(map(list, [coords]))   # <--- to have it iterable enclose it in []

    def move(self,distance):
        self._coords = distance

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self._coords[key]

class Point(Shape):
    def __init__(self,coords):
        super(Point, self).__init__(coords)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = Point((0, 0))

    p.move((1, 1))
    # the self._coords is a list, so fetch them by index like
    assert p[0], p[1] == (1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem in this exercise is that I cannot change the def init method of Shape and everything under name = main. So I cannot do what you propose. I can change Point or move and get items

Comment: Can't change ? coords needs to be a list, so calling it as: `p = Point([(0, 0)])` instead of `p = Point((0, 0))` will do too

Comment: No I cant change anything under main. Is there another solution?